# Why zero conditional mean assumption implies that u and x are uncorrelated?

Tags: regression, correlation, econometrics

In simple regression model, the *zero conditional mean assumption* implies *u and x are uncorrelated* as a slighter condition of zero conditional mean assumption. Then they use this to estimate. But I don't know **why zero conditional mean assumption implies this** after reading couple of books. Someone can explain?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If $E[u|x]=0$, then $$E[ux]=E[E[ux|x]]=E[xE[u|x]]=0$$
which means $\operatorname{cov}(u,x)=E[ux]-E[u]E[x]=0$ because also we have
$$E[u]=E[E[u|x]]=E[0]=0$$

Comment: Why you put `x` outside of the expected value if it is a random variable?

Comment: If you mean in the first line, i.e. $E[ux|x]$, $x$ is given so it can be removed from the inside of the expectation.